Checking if copy_file_range() and ioctl_ficlone() are available on linux
The man pages for copy_file_range() and ioctl_ficlone() document that the syscalls first appeared in Linux 4.5.
From this question: Is there a macro definition to check the Linux kernel version?, I found out how to detect the kernel version at compile-time:
#include <linux/version.h>

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,16)
...
#else
...

But man page says 4.5, there's no third number (whatever minor, major, or patch it is). How do I then detect if the kernel version is 4.5 or above?
The use-case is:
#if KERNEL_VERSION >= 4.5
    /* Use ioctl_ficlone()/copy_file_range(). */
#else
    /* Fall back to sendfile(). */
#endif


If run-time check is acceptable, then you can use syscall and check if those system calls exist or not

Just use 0 for the third number, e.g. KERNEL_VERSION(4,5,0). Note, this check only applies to kernel code, not userspace code. From userspace, it will give you the kernel version that the userspace kernel headers (part of the C library) were compiled against, which is usually a lower bound on the version of the actual running kernel.

@IanAbbott Thank you. But now I am confused, should I be trying to detect the version the headers were compiled against, or the actual running kernel?

Well, for compile time checks you can check if the FICLONE is defined by #include <linux/fs.h>. For run-time checks you could check the errno value when the FICLONE ioctl fails. An errno value of ENOTTY means that the ioctl is either not supported at all, or not supported for the particular file descriptor. You could also check kernel information at run-time using the uname function call.
